# Request Method "DELETE" not calling a method in web service

Tags: c#, android, web-services, httpurlconnection

I need to call the method cancel, but the system does not call the method and no error is shown.

```
url = new URL("http://localhost/api/Service.svc/Method/cancel");
con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString("user:password".getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP ));
con.setRequestMethod("DELETE");
con.connect();
```

And in my server C#:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "DELETE", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, 
RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
UriTemplate = "/cancel")]
void Cancel();
```

What is missing?

UPDATE:
  I insert the code `con.getResponseCode()` and return the value 401. What is this?

Comment: it is very unlikely that there is no error at all. post more context code in the android part, and check your logcat again

Comment: I insert the code `con.getResponseCode()` and return the value 401. What is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was solve this problem. After insert the code `con.getResponseCode()`, the system return 410 (unauthorized). Looking for this, found the real cause: the structure web service WCF ins't supported the verb "Delete".

I changed "Delete" to "POST" and the application run correctly.

Thanks!!